# How to truncate text from left instead of right in header title ?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

when title text are more in length than jquery-mobile truncate text with 3 dots (...) at the end (right side), but I want the same in left side. My purpose is to show text from right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is CSS work (text-overflow: ellipsis).

You can workaround (**on Firefox**) your need by telling that your text is right-to-left written, adding `direction: rtl` in the CSS.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2evzvf45/1/

```css
.rtl {
    
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    direction:rtl;
    width:150px;
    height:1.2em;
    font-size:12px;
}

.normal {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:150px;
    height:1.2em;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='rtl'>Long text is so long oh my is long indeed</h1>

<h1 class='normal'>Long text is so long oh my is long indeed</h1>
```

Comment: @micheal Dots showing in left side that is good but last words are not showing. My purpose is to show last words (if truncates ) and dots in left side (in case not possible to show whole text). As in example (...my is long indeed) like that.

Comment: @BholaNathMahto Well that's what it does on Firefox, but I just tried on IE and Chrome and you're right it's not doing the same

Comment: @BholaNathMahto Apparently Chrome as a bug with mixing rtl and ltr.. Just found some fiddler with a javascript function to cut text.  http://jsfiddle.net/x1Lvq2ex/

Answer (score -1):

The Previous example is working perfect, except you have a text with numbers + text. Then the number will be switched to the end.
Try: **1234 5678 Text 1111**

You will see "1234" at the end. I don't understand why the numbers are treated differently.